# Как в Eclipse быстро переписать несколько аргументов у ранее написанного метода?

Tags: java, eclipse

Когда первый раз пишешь метод, имеющий несколько аргументов, Content Assist печатает шаблон метода и позволяет с помощью кнопки Tab быстро заполнить подряд все аргументы.
Но я не могу найти, как это сделать, если метод уже написан ранее.

1. Так выглядит при первичной записи:

[image: Так выглядит при первичной записи]

2. А так после:

[image: А так после]

Вопрос кроется в описании.
Как в случае второй картинки сделать так, чтоб быстро переписать все 4 аргумента?
Спасибо.